# Squares in different bases

Tags: square-numbers

In base 5, 121 is 25+10+1=36=6*6

In base 6 121 is 36+12+1=49=7*7

In base 7 121 is 49+14+1=64=8*8

In base 5 144 is 25+20+4=49=7*7

In base 6 144 is 36+24+4=64=8*8

Can someone please explain why there seems to be this pattern? Thanks

Rik

Comment: It's simply $(x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1$ and $(x+2)^2=x^2+4x+4$.

Comment: $49+14+1$ and $54$ and $6\cdot6$ are three different numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in any base $b$ (assuming $b>2$), we have
$$
11^2=(10+1)^2=100+20+1
$$
And, assuming $b>4$, we have
$$
12^2=(10+2)^2=100+40+4
$$
Similarly, whenever $b>9$, you are going to find
$$
13^2=169
$$